# BrowserSync with Gulp in Visual Studio ISS Express using Angular 2

Tags: angular, gulp

I have used Gulp to build the files and push it to the build directory.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const del = require("del");
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');


/**
 * Remove build directory.
 */
gulp.task('clean', (cb) => {
    return del(["build"], cb);
});

/**
 * Compile TypeScript sources and create sourcemaps in build directory.
 */
gulp.task("compile", () => {
    var tsResult = gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});

/**
 * Copy all resources that are not TypeScript files into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("resources", () => {
    return gulp.src(["src/**/*", "!**/*.ts"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"))
});

/**
 * Copy all required libraries into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("libs", () => {
    return gulp.src([
            'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'rxjs/**',
            'zone.js/dist/**',
            '@angular/**'
    ], { cwd: "node_modules/**" }) /* Glob required here. */
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build/lib"));
});




/**
 * Build the project.
 */
gulp.task("build", ['compile', 'resources', 'libs'], () => {
    console.log("Build finished ...")
});
```

Now all my files are on build directory. I want to use BrowserSync option to reload the page when there is a change in html, typescript(ts) changes.

I found this but it's not working in Visual Studio; maybe it works on VS Code using lite-server.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    bs.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function () {
     gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', bs.reload);
});
```

I want to watch for changes on CSS, html, typescript files and then use compile task which compiles TypeScript to JavaScript and copy it on to build folder (not the original folder src/app) and the reload the browser upon changes.

I don't have routing now so using index.html as start page and the url is:

http://localhost:34756/src/index.html

and Index.html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 TypeScript Gulp QuickStart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="../build/lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../build/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's still relevant, but if you just need to recompile ts files on save just add "compileOnSave": true, on the top of tsconfig.json